# Extremely weird NullPointerException when reading in a File Android

Tags: java, android, file-io, simple-framework

Here is the code:

```
Thread clientThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    client = new Client();
                    quest = client.readFile();
                    Log.v("Client string", quest);

                    //File file = new File(myContext.getFilesDir(), "questionnaire.xml");
                    //BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
                    //bw.write(quest);
                    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("questionnaire", ".xml");
                    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
                    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(fout);
                    out.println(quest);//InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(quest.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    //getResources().op
                    try {
                    Serializer serializer = new Persister();
                    responseToQuestionnaire = serializer.read(ResponseToQuestionnaire.class, tempFile);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {}
                    Log.v("Let's seeeeee",responseToQuestionnaire.getQuestionnaireTemplate().toString());

                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
//              try {
//                  OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
//                          openFileOutput(currentQuestionnaire.getName(),
//                                  Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
//                  outputStreamWriter.write(client.readFile());
//                  outputStreamWriter.close();
//              } catch (IOException e) {
//                  Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
//              }
            }
        };
        clientThread.start();
```

The code throws a Null Pointer  exception even when quest is a full length string that prints in log perfectly fine. I tried multiple ways of saving the file but SimpleXML doesn't serialize string... only XML files.

Comment: please add the logcat

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZzT81vis

Comment: Which line no 159 is in your BasicQuestionActivity.java

Comment: Log.v("Let's seeeeee",responseToQuestionnaire.getQuestionnaireTemplate().toString());

Comment: are you getting some Exception and that's why your your variable responseToQuestionnaire is null so before that line put e.printStackTrace(); this then you will got proper error.

Comment: I know that this is happening. What I think is going on is that there is a problem with writing the file with the string. The string is not fully saved with a FileWriter and not saved at all with a BufferedWriter... I don't know how to interpret this.

Comment: Pretty sure "getQuestionnaireTemplate()" is the part that's null since you're only setting "responseToQuestionnaire" (unless it's built internally)

Comment: That's not the problem as the object there should have been created earlier with the text file that's not saving properly.

Comment: Either your `responseToQuestionnaire.getQuestionnaireTemplate()` is `null`, or `responseToQuestionnaire` is `null`. It is that easy. Set a breakpoint, use the debugger, check this out. By the way, did you set the permissions to read/write to external storage inside your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Buffered streams don't necessarily write the data until they have to. Try closing the output stream before you call the read() method.